# How to use multiline commit messages with github?

Tags: git, github

I have two commits with multiline messages. But in bother cases on github I see only first line.

```
commit da202cdb5085290a6498c434a0d9388d880fe8c8
Date:   Tue Oct 1 16:30:02 2013 +0200

    Line 1

    Line 2

commit c58f91213428728836b1364ecc111ba71e7c91c6
Date:   Tue Oct 1 15:47:12 2013 +0200

    [f] unique primary key for id in picture
    [+] join_db script
```

https://github.com/antofa/autowp_test/commits/dev

I use next commands for commits:

> git commit -F commit_message.txt
>
> git commit -m "Line 1" -m "Line 2"

Can github work with multiline commit messages and how?

Comment: Were you running into issues when you typed `git commit`, then typed a commit message with new lines in it?  I've not run into that issue...and I would imagine that GitHub would be fine with it, too.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is... I see both lines in the link you provided.  In the commit listing, GitHub only shows the first line, because it's meant to be a summary.  If you look at the commit itself, such as [here](https://github.com/antofa/autowp_test/commit/c58f91213428728836b1364ecc111ba71e7c91c6), then you see the complete message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All lines are there in your Github history, but by default only the subject (first line) is shown in the short history overview.

Click the `...` next to a commit's subject line to show the full comment.

*Edit:*
Added screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I guess, that in github exist setting, that by default will show all lines of commit message.

Comment: no, there is no such setting. any history browsers i know which show large portions of history (with the notable exception of `git log`) only show the subject line in the overview. There are detail pages for a reason.